# why must use boost::is_any_of when using boost::split?

Tags: c++, boost

why must one use boost::is_any_of when using boost::split ?

When I used: `boost::split(split_res, someStr, ".");`

I get an error.

Comment: Please take the time to read the [tour] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: looks like 3rd parameter is predicat `boost::split(split_res, someStr, [](char ch){return ch == '.';});`

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

Because the API is designed that way (e.g. it allows for dynamic predicates that take into account things like locale).

> But how could I know? I got a weird error

You can read the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_idp441369712.html). If you use it incorrectly, it's the compiler's job to tell you about it.

> This seems too complicated for me

Don't use it. Wrap it in a function with a simpler interface that you like.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4bf196fdf58988d)</kbd>**

```
namespace my {
    template <typename R = std::vector<std::string> >
        R split(std::string const& input, char delim = '.') {
            R v;
            boost::split(v, input, boost::algorithm::is_any_of(std::array<char,1>{delim}));
            return v;
        }
}
```

Comment: added a sample to demonstrate a wrapper function http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4bf196fdf58988d

Comment: Somewhat simpler (and possibly more efficient): `boost::split(v, input, [delim](char c){ return delim == c; });`

Comment: @zett42 I was hoping it would optimize away, but you're right at least on some configs: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca90a86f057c2233 and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a1ace3196277df2